# Server Error 500 on every Ajax Call

Tags: views, ajax

we have a problem that we get a internal server error on about every ajax call. The example below happens when editing a view clicking "add filter" and directly click on abort. It also happens when making changes to a view. At first glance the change seemed to be ignored but after refreshing the pages the changes will be visible.

[image: Picture of the error]

When accessing the URL which throws the error we get a valid json string (checked with jsonlint.com).

Our server logs sadly show nothing interesting. I would appreciate any kind of hint where to look for a solution.

**Edit:**
The nojs version seems to work fine but that's no solution in the long term :/

Comment: You can try to enable error dsiplay in php config, and look at Firebug's console tab.

Comment: Doing so just gets me the Ajax Call with a 500. Even though there is a 500 I get a valid JSON as an answer

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Please have a look in admin/reports/dblog around the time you cause this error, any critical errors? Are CTools and views both up to date?

Answer (score 1):

Look at your PHP error log. It should give you the file and line number it's having an issue with.

If you can, copy and paste the last few lines of the error log on here for us to look at.

Answer (score -1):

When I have something like this it has always to do with the .htaccess file.
Or maybe you just haven't enabled clean url's or something like that.

**EDIT**
Is there somthing like this in your htaccess file

```
 RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make sure it's uncommented

Comment: Clean URLs were enabled, the .htaccess is the standard file generated by drupal. Is there a way to let drupal rebuild it from scratch or can you give me a hint for what to look in the .htaccess file?

Comment: Are your rewriterules enabled? check edit

Answer (score -1):

Create a separate page using `hook_menu` and write the same logic on the page where you are hitting. Also pass the arguments if any, if the newly created page is working fine then just replace that page with this newly created page.